# How to attach fragment to activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have activity with fragments:

```
for (String tab_name : tabs) {
    getActionBar().addTab(mActionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                          .setTabListener(this));
}

FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction().add(new FirstFragment(), "TEST").commit();
fm.beginTransaction().add(new SecondFragment(), "TEST").commit();
fm.beginTransaction().add(new ThirdFragment(), "TEST").commit();
```

When I want to call new Activity from my SecondFragment:

```
Intent intent =  new Intent(App.context, SomeActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

It crashes with this error:

```
03-22 00:22:19.439: E/AndroidRuntime(17438): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment ... not attached to Activity
```

`App.context` is from MainActivity:

```
App.context = getApplicationContext();
```

What I can know that to attach fragment to activity, can be done by adding the fragment to fragmentManager, but it still crash. What I am wrong here?

Comment: holding a static context is VERY VERY BAD, it causes a memory leak

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
Intent intent =  new Intent(App.context, SomeActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

use

```
Intent intent =  new Intent(getActivity(), SomeActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

instead of using `App.context` use `getActivty()`

Comment: It returns null, although I create variable and get activity from onAttach and use that variable in my method..

Comment: why do you want to create a variable? also share me the onAttach code

Comment: To pass activity. Got this resolved anyway, but startActivity still crash my app.

Comment: what exception do you get now?

Comment: Still the same. isAdded() still returns false because my fragment still not attached to activity.

Answer (score 0):

As holding a context is very bad.
Just use this

```
Intent intent =  new Intent(getActivity(), SomeActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It returns null, although I create variable and get activity from onAttach and use that variable in my method..